# Joi concat with object nested in array

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

I currently have this Joi scheme:

```
scheme1 = Joi.object({
  arr: Joi.array.items(Joi.object().keys({
    value: Joi.number()
  }))
})
```

And another one (that I can't edit/read) which looks the same with different object keys

```
scheme2 = Joi.object({
  arr: Joi.array.items(Joi.object({
    otherValue: Joi.number(),
    moreValues: Joi.string()
  }))
})
```

I now need to merge these in such a way that I get something like this:

```
result = Joi.object({
  arr: Joi.array.items(Joi.object({
    value: Joi.number(),
    otherValue: Joi.number(),
    moreValues: Joi.string()
  }))
})
```

By using `scheme1.concat(scheme2)` I only get:

```
Joi.array.items(object1, object2)
```

How can I do this, without modifying or accessing (apart from concat) the second scheme?

Comment: Seems like it isn't possible right now and won't be in the future :/
https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/978